# How to interchange place of toggle and label in Angular8 using Bootstrap4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Hi i am using Angular8 with Bootstrap 4, here i have used checkboxes for one of the screen, so the checkbox comes first and then the label comes, i need to give label first and then checkbox. Can anyone help me to make it possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="userInfoForm">
  <div class="col pt-lg-4 max-50">
    <label for="" class="font-weight-bold">Permissions</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="DoesUserhaveaccess" formControlName="accesstoCrs">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="DoesUserhaveaccess">Access? </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Label and Toggle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-fields-stack-overflow-yspse3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [stackblitz forked from yours](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-fields-stack-overflow-zaa7sn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css), I redefined the `left` properties for the `before` and `after` pseudo elements. This places the switch after the text and to align all the switch, I added a `width` to the label container in order to be big enough for every elements in it.
It's the only way I found to swap the label and the switch.

Comment: Thanks for respose, but if we do so, the values are not binding, in the access, toggle, it must be checked, but it appears to be unchecked, that is the issue even i was facing

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, check again my stackblitz, I printed the form value in the html and it's working. Plus you had a typo in the access's label `for`, at the end you forgot a `to` It was `DoesUserhaveaccess` instead of `DoesUserhaveaccessto`.  I added it in my stackblitz

Comment: Ya thanks, its working now, but the toggles are not in order, i mean they are not in straight line, can we make that to get aligned properly

Comment: Fixed the checkboxes to be in straight line in my updated answer hope it helps.

Comment: you can play with the width property to fit your need of spacing between labels and switches

Comment: Hi, how do we add extra class to this and add all the styles you have given, actually if i use the same css, it is affecting me in other places so, but your solution is working fine

Comment: it is updated, I just added custom-switch--withLabelOnLeft class on the custom-switch element then in the css I added the same

Comment: If it works for you please upvote and mark as accepted answer, thank you

Comment: sure will vote and accept answer, its working fine

Answer (score 2):

With some `CSS` you could fix it like this:

**Updated:** If you wan't to `align` the `checkboxes` with text that differs in lenght I also added that to the answer.

```css
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::before,
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::after{
  right: -1.5rem;
  left: initial;
  }

.label-align-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
}​
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin:20px;">

<div class="row" [formGroup]="userInfoForm">
  <div class="col pt-lg-4 max-50">
    <label for="" class="font-weight-bold">Permissions</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch custom-control-right ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="DoesUserhaveaccess" formControlName="accesstoCrs">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="DoesUserhaveaccess">Access? </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Align checkboxes with different text length -->

<div class="row" [formGroup]="userInfoForm">
  <div class="col pt-lg-4 max-50">
    <label for="" class="font-weight-bold">Permissions</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch custom-control-right ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="DoesUserhaveaccess2" formControlName="accesstoCrs">
          <label class=" label-align-text custom-control-label" for="DoesUserhaveaccess2">Access? </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch custom-control-right ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="DoesUserhaveaccess3" formControlName="accesstoCrs">
          <label  class="label-align-text custom-control-label" for="DoesUserhaveaccess3">Access longer text? </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch custom-control-right ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="DoesUserhaveaccess4" formControlName="accesstoCrs">
          <label class="label-align-text custom-control-label" for="DoesUserhaveaccess4">Access longer text much longer? </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it is not working in my case, i have tried swapping label and input in the demo shared, but that doesnt work. Any other solution?

Comment: updated answer, hope it helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for response, but could you please fork that in stackblitz, i am stil not getting my toggles aligned

Comment: i am able to see my demo only, once you have made chnages, please click on fork and share me that url, so il get your changes

Comment: Here you go my bad: https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-fields-stack-overflow-kuf7gh?file=src/app/app.component.css